# Add AWS SQS Permission to all Principals through SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to create an AWS SQS queue through the Java SDK, and then add all permissions for all users. I can create the queue fine, but I'm struggling to know what value I can pass in for the Principals. This is what my code looks like:

```
CreateQueueRequest createQueueRequest = new CreateQueueRequest(queueName).withAttributes(attributes);
CreateQueueResult createQueueResult = amazonSqs.createQueue(createQueueRequest);
String queueUrl = createQueueResult.getQueueUrl();

amazonSqs.addPermission(queueUrl, "*", ????, Arrays.asList("*"));
```

The `???` is what I'm not sure on. I've tried `Arrays.asList("*")` but it complains about it not being valid. In the web console, there is a checkbox for Everyone, and I'm just wanting to do the same thing in the SDK. Is there some value I can pass for this?

**--- UPDATE ---**

I've been able to accomplish this another way through a `Policy`:

```
String queueUrl = createQueueResult.getQueueUrl();
GetQueueAttributesResult getQueueAttributesResult = amazonSqs.getQueueAttributes(queueUrl, Arrays.asList(QUEUE_ARN_ATTRIBUTE_NAME));
String queueArn = getQueueAttributesResult.getAttributes().get(QUEUE_ARN_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

if (needToSetPolicy)
{

  Policy allAccessPolicy = new Policy("SQSAllAccess", Arrays.asList(
    new Statement(Effect.Allow)
        .withActions(() -> "SQS:*")
        .withPrincipals(Principal.All)
        .withId("SQSAllAccessStatement")
        .withResources(new Resource(queueArn))
  ));
  Map<String, String> policyMap = new HashMap<>(1);
  policyMap.put(POLICY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, allAccessPolicy.toJson());

  amazonSqs.setQueueAttributes(queueUrl, policyMap);
}
```

It seems like there should be a better/easier way to do this. Are there any better/cleaner/easier ways of doing this?

Comment: Haven't found a solution myself, from what I understand it only works with a list of AWS accound ids. I'm trying to get the second snippet you posted to work, but what's the value of POLICY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME?

Comment: @DannyPetrunov It is set to "Policy" This is based on the javadoc found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/SetQueueAttributesRequest.html#withAttributes-java.util.Map-

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin using the constants from the SDK

```
val policy: Policy = Policy("AllowAllSendMessage", listOf(Statement(Effect.Allow)
    .withActions(SQSActions.SendMessage)
    .withPrincipals(Principal.All)
    .withId("AllowAllSendMessage")
    .withResources(Resource(queueArn))))
_sqs.setQueueAttributes(SetQueueAttributesRequest()
    .withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
    .withAttributes(mapOf(QueueAttributeName.Policy.toString() to policy.toJson())))
```